# How to remove new lines within double quotes?

Tags: regex, bash, file, ubuntu, newline

How can I remove new line inside the `"` from a file?

For example:

```
"one", 
"three
four",
"seven"
```

So I want to remove the `\n` between the `three` and `four`. Should I use regular expression, or I have to read that's file per character with program?

Answer (score 31):

To handle specifically those newlines that are in doubly-quoted strings and leave those alone that are outside them, using GNU awk (for `RT`):

```
gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' file
```

This works by splitting the file along `"` characters and removing newlines in every other block. With a file containing

```
"one",
"three
four",
12,
"seven"
```

this will give the result

```
"one",
"threefour",
12,
"seven"
```

Note that it does not handle escape sequences. If strings in the input data can contain `\"`, such as `"He said: \"this is a direct quote.\""`, then it will not work as desired.

Comment: I had to use ``gsub(/[\r\n]+/, " ")`` to make it work to my needs.

Comment: This worked so +1. I had to space out the %s%s line `printf("%s %s", $0, RT)` since I needed spacing between words.

Answer (score 5):

You can print those lines starting with `"`. If they don't, accumulate its content into a variable and print it later on:

```
$ awk '/^"/ {if (f) print f; f=$0; next} {f=f FS $0} END {print f}' file
"one", 
"three four",
"seven"
```

Since we are always printing the previous block of text, note the need of `END` to print the last stored value after processing the full file.

Comment: This seems a bit brittle. If anything is supposed to appear outside double quotes (for example: `"one",\n"three\nfour",\n12,\n"seven"`), it can remove newlines that aren't inside quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` for that:

```
sed -r '/^"[^"]+$/{:a;N;/",/!ba;s/\n/ /g}' text
```

The command searches for lines which start with a doublequote  but don't contain another doublequote: `/^"[^"]+$/`

If such a line is found a label `:a` is defined to mark the start of a loop. Using the `N` command we append another line from input to the current buffer. If the new line again doesn't contain the closing double quote `/",/!` we step again to label `a` using `ba` unless we found the closing quote.

If the quote was found all newlines gettting replaces by a space `s/\n/ /g` and the buffer gets automatically printed by sed.

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (m/^\"/) { print "\n"; }
    print;
}


__DATA__
"one", 
"three
four",
"seven"
```

But taking the *specific* case of `csv` style data, I'd suggest using a perl module called `Text::CSV` which parses CSV properly - and treats the 'element with a linefeed' part of the preceeding row.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } );

open( my $input, "<", "input.csv" ) or die $!;

while ( my $row = $csv->getline($input) ) {
    for (@$row) {
        #remove linefeeds in each 'element'. 
        s/\n/ /g;
        #print this specific element ('naked' e.g. without quotes). 
        print;
        print ",";
    }
    print "\n";
}
close($input);
```

Answer (score 1):

tested in a bash

purpose: replace newline inside double quote by \n

works for unix newline (\n), windows newline (\r\n) and mac newline (\n\r)

> echo -e '"line1\nline2"'`

```
line1
line2
```

> echo -e '"line1\nline2"' | gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\r?\n\r?/, "\n") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }'

`line1\nline2`

Answer (score 0):

```
 my $csv_in = 'Text::CSV'->new({binary => 1,
                             sep_char => ";",
                             auto_diag => 1
                             })
or die "CANNOT USE CSV: " . 'Text::CSV'->error_diag;

my $csv_out = 'Text::CSV'->new({ binary => 1,
                             eol => "\n",
                             sep_char => ";",
                             always_quote => 1,
                             auto_diag => 1
                             })
or die "CANNOT USE CSV: " . 'Text::CSV'->error_diag;

logger('LOG-3','PROCESSING FILE :'."\n".$source_feed_date_file);

try{
    # Inbound file reader with no encoding specified ==>
    open(my $CSV_FILE, '<', $source_feed_date_file) ;
    # Outbound file writer with UTF8 encoding ==>
    open(my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $dest_feed_date_file) ;
    my $rx = 0;
    while (my $row = $csv_in->getline($CSV_FILE)) {
        s/\n|\r|\0|[^\x00-\x7F]//g for @$row;
        $csv_out->print ($fh, $row);

        if( $rx % 1000 == 0) {
            print "$rx \n";
        }
        $rx+=1;
    }
    print "Total Number Of Records processed:";
    print $rx ;
    my $e1 = time();
    printf("\n\nTime elapsed for %s : %.2f\n", $file,$e1 - $s1);
  } catch {
        my $e = shift;
        print $e;
        logger('LOG-4','PROCESSING FAILED FOR FILE :'."\n".$source_feed_date_file);
        exit 1;
    };
```

http://www.riveriq.com/blogs/2020/02/how-to-remove-new-lines-within-double-quotes