# Bash: Parse CSV with quotes, commas and newlines

Tags: bash, csv, awk, cut, gawk

Say I have the following csv file:

```
 id,message,time
 123,"Sorry, This message
 has commas and newlines",2016-03-28T20:26:39
 456,"It makes the problem non-trivial",2016-03-28T20:26:41
```

I want to write a bash command that will return only the time column.  i.e.

```
time
2016-03-28T20:26:39
2016-03-28T20:26:41
```

What is the most straight forward way to do this?  You can assume the availability of standard unix utils such as awk, gawk, cut, grep, etc.

Note the presence of "" which escape , and newline characters which make trivial attempts with

```
cut -d , -f 3 file.csv
```

futile.

Comment: Use a language with a real CSV parser, not `bash`.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with @chepner. For this task I would use `Python` or `Ruby` instead of Bash.

Comment: @chepner From some time ago,  [tag:bash] offer a CSV parser as *loadable builtin*! See [How to parse CSV in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658)

Comment: See [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Comment: You can use `awk` command to solve the problem. Here is a simple and direct way:

```bash
awk -F, 'NR > 1 {gsub(/"/, "", $3); print $3}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 18):

As [chepner said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287982/bash-parse-csv-with-quotes-commas-and-newlines/36288089#comment60201753_36287982), you are encouraged to use a programming language which is able to parse *csv*.

Here comes an example in python:

```py
import csv

with open('a.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print(row[-1]) # row[-1] gives the last column
```

Comment: See OP's problem. He has new line characters within the quotes. Awk will not consider that

Comment: @realspirituals Yeah, that's true. I've replaced `awk` by `python`.

Comment: Minor correction - file should be open rather in 'text mode' than 'binary mode'  - use `rt` instead `rb` in open().

Answer (score 7):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150640/how-to-remove-new-lines-within-double-quotes)

```
gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' file.csv \
 | awk -F, '{print $NF}'
```

To handle specifically those newlines that are in doubly-quoted strings and leave those alone that are outside them, using `GNU awk` (for `RT`):

```
gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' file
```

This works by splitting the file along `"` characters and removing newlines in every other block.

**Output**

```
time
2016-03-28T20:26:39
2016-03-28T20:26:41
```

Then use awk to split the columns and display the last column

Answer (score 6):

CSV is a format which needs a proper parser (i.e. which can't be parsed with regular expressions alone). If you have [Python](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/) installed, use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead of plain BASH.

If not, consider [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/) which has a lot of powerful tools to process CSV files from the command line.

See also:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/is-there-a-robust-command-line-tool-for-processing-csv-files

Comment: FWIW, a csv probably could be parsed with regex, but it would definitely be a pain.

Comment: Part of the reason it's annoying is that csv is actually a loose family of dialects and it would be particularly hard to find a one size fits all regex for all the variations.

Answer (score 1):

**`csvcut` from `csvkit` example**

csvkit was mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36288388/895245 but here's the example.

Install:

```
pip install csvkit
```

Sample CSV input file:

main.csv

```
a,"b
c",d
e,f
```

Get the first column:

```
csvcut -c 1 main.csv
```

which outputs:

```
a
e
```

or to get the second column:

```
csvcut -c 1 main.csv
```

which outputs the following valid CSV with a single column:

```
"b
c"
f
```

Or to swap the two columns around:

```
csvcut -c 2,1 main.csv
```

which outputs another valid CSV file:

```
"b
c",a
f,e
```

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04, csvkit==1.1.1.

**csvtool**

This is another good one. It is a compiled executable rather than Python script, so it can be much faster for large datasets. And the `format` operation is useful if you want to print a single column without escapes, which can be useful so long as there are no multiline entries, and `csvkit` does not seem to support.

Install:

```
sudo apt install csvtool
```

Sample usage:

```
printf 'a,"b,c",d\ne,"f""g",h\n' | csvtool format '%(2)\n' -
```

output:

```
b,c
f"g
```

See also: [How to extract one column of a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602181/how-to-extract-one-column-of-a-csv-file)

Tested on Ubuntu 23.10, csvtool 2.4-3.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` alternative using FS

```
$ awk -F'"' '!(NF%2){getline remainder;$0=$0 OFS remainder}
                NR>1{sub(/,/,"",$NF); print $NF}' file

2016-03-28T20:26:39
2016-03-28T20:26:41
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar when attempting to deal with lspci -m output, but the embedded newlines would need to be escaped first (though IFS=, should work here, since it abuses bash' quote evaluation).
Here's an example

```
f:13.3 "System peripheral" "Intel Corporation" "Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel Target Address Decoder" -r01 "Super Micro Computer Inc" "Device 0838"
```

And the only reasonable way I can find to bring that into bash is along the lines of:

```
# echo 'f:13.3 "System peripheral" "Intel Corporation" "Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel Target Address Decoder" -r01 "Super Micro Computer Inc" "Device 0838"' | { eval array=($(cat)); declare -p array; }
declare -a array='([0]="f:13.3" [1]="System peripheral" [2]="Intel Corporation" [3]="Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel Target Address Decoder" [4]="-r01" [5]="Super Micro Computer Inc" [6]="Device 0838")'
#
```

Not a full answer, but might help!

Comment: "Reasonable" only if you trust your data.  A piece of hardware that reads out as `"Super 1337 $(rm -rf ~) Hey I Changed Your DMI Info"` would lead to bad times.

Comment: sure.. any bash comment with 'eval' in it should probably be flagged 'caveat emptor'

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla bash script

save this code as parse_csv.sh, give it execution privilege (chmod +x parse_csv.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash                             
# vim: ts=4 sw=4 hidden nowrap          
# @copyright Copyright © 2021 Carlos Barcellos <carlosbar at gmail.com>         
# @license https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.en.html
                                    
if [ "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "--help" -o "$1" = "-v" ]; then
    echo "parse csv 0.1"                    
    echo ""
    echo "parse_csv.sh [csv file] [delimiter]"
    echo "  csv file    csv file to parse; default stdin"                           
    echo "  delimiter   delimiter to use. default is comma"
    exit 0
fi                                                                              
delim=,
if [ $# -ge 1 ]; then
    [ -n "$1" ] && file="$1"
    [ -n "$2" -a "$2" != "\"" ] && delim="$2"
fi                                                                             
processLine() {
    if [[ ! "$1" =~ \" ]]; then
        (                                               
           IFSS="$delim" fields=($1)                                                             
           echo  "${fields[@]}"  
        )
        return 0
    fi
    under_scape=0
    fields=()
    acc=
    for (( x=0; x < ${#1}; x++ )); do
        if [ "${1:x:1}" = "${delim:0:1}" -o $((x+1)) -ge ${#1} ] && [ $under_scape -ne 1 ]; then
            [ "${1:x:1}" != "${delim:0:1}" ] && acc="${acc}${1:x:1}"
            fields+=($acc)
            acc=
        elif [ "${1:x:1}" = "\"" ]; then
            if [ $under_scape -eq 1 ] && [ "${1:x+1:1}" = "\"" ]; then
                acc="${acc}${1:x:1}"
            else
                under_scape=$((!under_scape))                                           
            fi
            [ $((x+1)) -ge ${#1} ] && fields+=($acc)                                
        else
            acc="${acc}${1:x:1}"                                                    
        fi
    done
    echo  "${fields[@]}"
    return 0
 } 
 while read -r line; do
     processLine "$line"
 done < ${file:-/dev/stdin}
```

Then use: parse_csv.sh "csv file". To print only the last col, you can change the *echo  "${fields[@]}"* to  *echo  "${fields[-1]}"*

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue! Use the [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS) module to handle CSV.

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -we 'csv(in => $ARGV[0],
                                 on_in => sub { $_[1] = [ $_[1][-1] ] })
                            ' -- file.csv
```

- the `csv` subroutine processes the csv
- `in` specifies the input file, `$ARGV[0]` contains the first command line argument, i.e. `file.csv` here
- `on_in` specifies code to run. It gets the current row as the second argument, i.e. `$_[1]`. We just set the whole row to the contents of the last column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking it.

```
$: echo time; grep -Eo '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$' file
time
2016-03-28T20:26:39
2016-03-28T20:26:41
```

If you want to check for that comma just to be sure,

```
$: echo time; sed -En '/,[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/{ s/.*,//; p; }' file
time
2016-03-28T20:26:39
2016-03-28T20:26:41
```

Answer (score 0):

[csvquote](https://github.com/dbro/csvquote) is designed for exactly this kind of thing. It santizes the file (reversibly) and allows awk to depend on commas being field separators and newlines being record separators.

Answer (score -3):

```
awk -F, '!/This/{print $NF}' file

time
2016-03-28T20:26:39
2016-03-28T20:26:41
```