# Split String to array with regex in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I need to split a string into an array in bash. However, not by a fixed delimiter character, but by a regular expression. Here are the details:

I have a CSV file containing millions of lines of the following format:

```
123,"usrlogin1","usrname2","companyname1","email@example.com","1970-01-01 00:00:00","USR",0,1
```

However, some fields may contain escaped quotation marks `\"` and commas within strings, so a line might just as well look like this:

```
123,"usrlogin1","usrname2","The \"awesome\" company, NA","email@example.com","1970-01-01 00:00:00","USR",0,1
```

I need to split this file by the correct commas, that is to say those which are outside of non-escaped quotation marks.

Desired output:

```
123
usrlogin1
usrname2
The &quot;awesome&quot; company, NA
email@example.com
1970-01-01 00:00:00
USR
0
1
```

This is where I am at:

```
#!/bin/sh

#read file line by line
while IFS='' read -r line; do

    #replace escaped quotation marks (\") with (&quot;)
    line=$(echo $line | sed 's/\\"/\&quot\;/g')

    #split this line now by commas
    #TODO


done < "$1"
```

At the point of `TODO`, I would like to use the following regex as delimiter for splitting my string into an array:

`(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xB7rQ7/1

How can I split the `$line` by the regex above?

Comment: You might consider a real CSV parser instead. [bash: Parse CSV with quotes, commas and newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287982/bash-parse-csv-with-quotes-commas-and-newlines) is a good place to start.

Comment: ...if you want to run a regex natively in bash, it has to be valid ERE, which the one you gave isn't (ERE has no `(?!` syntax and no `\B`s, for example; there's a valid POSIX ERE equivalent for many backslash-whatever shortcuts, but I don't know what `\B` is offhand to say).

Comment: BTW, `echo $line | ...` is buggy -- let's say your CSV contains `"My * AWESOME * company"` as a field; the `*`s will be replaced with filenames in the directory where you're running your code unless you make it `echo "$line"`. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)

Comment: Your regex makes no sense. `[^"]*` at the end of a look-ahead group is pointless because it always matches (it can match the empty string). `\B` is also suspect: `"` is a quoting character no matter whether it lies on a non-word boundary.

Comment: Your `\"` replacement scheme isn't right for two reasons: 1. Afterwards you can't distinguish `\"` from a field that actually contains `&quot;` initially.  2. If you have a field that contains actual backslashes, they ought to be escaped as \\, meaning `"...\\"` (a literal backslash at the end of a quoted field) would turn into `"...\&quot;`.

Comment: "a file containing millions of lines" -- I would immediately look for a non-bash solution based on this statement. "a CSV file" -- doubly so.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I will scrap my current approach and work with a proper parser instead. Thanks a lot for pointing out all of the issues :)