# OpenCSVSerde escapeChar overriding quoteChar

Tags: sql, csv, hive, special-characters, hive-serde

I have a number of csv’s I’m importing into Hive and I’ve found that my escapeChar of a new line is being triggered even when it is within a quoted field, which is my quoteChar. Is there any straightforward way around this dilemma?

```
Line1field1 text,Line1field2 text,”Line1field3 text \n with new line”\n
Line2field1 text,”Line2field2 text, with comma”
```

Answer (score 2):

No way to fix it with text format in Hive.

OpenCSVSerDe does not handele embedded newlines, see this [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde)

Text formats like CSV, JSON, do not allow embedded newlines and SerDe's which work with text formats such as RegexSerDe, OpenCSVSerDe, JSONSerDe, LasySimpleSerDe do not handle embedded newlines.

You can store embedded newlines in binary formats: ORC, Parquet, Avro, but in different query tools newlines will cause line breaks and shift, though you can replace newlines with something if it is stored in binary format in the query. For text formats it is not possible, because record reader reads lines and serde receives separate lines.

The solution is to transform CSV before loading into hive and replace newlines with something else, or use binary format if possible.

Comment: Are you aware of any easy ways for me to transform the csv prior? It seems like it would be difficult to do since I will also have to account for the embedded escape characters

Comment: @Jgreen727 If newlines are between quotes, see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/29150640/2700344 If there are also escaped quotes - replace  them before. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47797207/2700344 Try to search, there are many such questions already asked